# flutter UI change positioned

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want design this type UI how can do this. Please help me
white color circle with bar should be change where the position some one click on the horizontal calendar

if some one click the horizontal  calendar want to change white color circle with bar clicked position

I try using  image and click date and hide other image , but difficult to get actual positioned

if anyone know this please help me ,

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the UI ? Do you also started with some code ?

Comment: hello I added  screen shot

Comment: So do you already have some code ? Can you provide a more detailed description about what you are looking for ? Did you try but nothing work or didn't even try ?

Comment: i did but cant do this

Comment: I have no idea, what you are asking. What do you want to change when someone clicks on a date, like the content of the circle? What were trying to use an image for? Just confused as to to what you are wanting to do?

Comment: I want some one click date and change  the circle

Comment: I agree with @CStark. The question is unclear, you should provide a more detailed description of your goal. What do you mean by "change the circle" ? The content ? Shape ? Color ?

Comment: white color circle with bar should be change where the position some one click on the horizontal calendar